# Why do I get setMessageLoggingBlock: called when playing video on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using a `UIWebView` to call a video list website, then the user chooses a video and `UIWebView` plays the video inline.

**But I keep getting this message:**

```
setMessageLoggingBlock: called
```

Then I can't get any message sent by the JavaScript. I googled, people may get this error because they have break points in their programs. But I don't have any break point.

So what's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It is an rtcreporting log which only appears when you are trying to run or stream the video on the simulator.
Run the app on device rather than in simulator.

Comment: Thanks, I will try on a device and let you know the result.